# Query about linkedin api v2

Tags: linkedin-api

I am developing an application of managing users personally owned companies comments, replies & messages. I am doing this via API. But Linkedin API v1 has very limited access. So I have two questions

1. Can i get the access of notifications, messages and replies via linkedin API v2?
2. How can i get the access of linkedin API v2?

Answer (score 0):

for the V2 API you need a linkedin partnership:
https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs
without the partnership you cannot access the data.
and on the message/replies api:

no its currently not possible
it will be possible in the near future, see here.
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/communications/messages

> Utilize Messages API to retrieve and send messages to your connections and more! API is coming soon.

Comment: And what about notifications??

Comment: no idea, never been able to find anything about notifications.